# Como hacer el pivote de una tabla en Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, subconsultas, pivot

Actualmente tengo una tabla de la siguiente forma.

```
Lunes           Martes           Miercoles      Jueves          Viernes         Sabado           Domingo
10:00 - 11:00   12:00 - 13:00   12:00 - 13:00   10:00 - 11:00   12:00 - 13:00   10:00 - 11:00   12:00 - 13:00
```

con la siguiente consulta.

```
select max(case when id = 1 then CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin) else 0 end) Lunes,
max(case when id = 2 then CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin) else 0 end) Martes,
max(case when id = 3 then CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin) else 0 end) Miercoles,
max(case when id = 4 then CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin) else 0 end) Jueves,
max(case when id = 5 then CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin) else 0 end) Viernes,
max(case when id = 6 then CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin) else 0 end) Sabado,
max(case when id = 7 then CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin) else 0 end) Domingo from
(
  select ct_dia.id,tb_dia_confighorario.hora_inicio,tb_dia_confighorario.hora_fin  from tb_dia_confighorario inner join tb_config_area_comun on tb_dia_confighorario.idConfigHorario=tb_config_area_comun.id
inner join ct_dia on tb_dia_confighorario.idDia=ct_dia.id where tb_dia_confighorario.idConfigHorario=1
) x
```

El problema que quiero resolver es el siguiente, actualmente la tabla de `tb_dia_confighorario` contiene un dia repetido que es el id 2 que vendria siendo martes con horarios diferentes, sin embargo en el resultado de la tabla no vienen esos dos horarios de martes o de cualquier otro dia que tenga mas de un horario y quisiera saber porque y como se podria resolver ya que lo que busco es que vengan todos los horarios por dia y los que no tengan horario ponerles un null por defecto.

```
id idCoidDia fecha              estatus inicio  fin
1   1   4   2022-08-02 12:11:40     1   10:00   11:00
2   1   1   2022-08-02 12:11:40     1   10:00   11:00
3   1   2   2022-08-02 12:11:40     1   10:00   11:00
4   1   6   2022-08-02 12:11:40     1   10:00   11:00
5   1   2   2022-08-02 12:12:07     1   12:00   13:00
6   1   3   2022-08-02 12:12:07     1   12:00   13:00
7   1   5   2022-08-02 12:12:07     1   12:00   13:00
8   1   7   2022-08-02 12:12:07     1   12:00   13:00
```

> Nota: cambie el nombre de las columnas de arriba para que se adecuaran
> al foro.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] en el resultado de la tabla no vienen esos dos horarios de martes o de cualquier otro dia que tenga mas de un horario y quisiera saber porque y como se podria resolver

#### ¿Por qué?

Porque estas utilizando `max` y este solo devuelve el registro cuyo valor es el mayor.

#### ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Podrías usar [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

**Ejemplo:**

```sql
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(id = 1, CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin), NULL)) Lunes,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(id = 2, CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin), NULL)) Martes,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(id = 3, CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin), NULL)) Miercoles,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(id = 4, CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin), NULL)) Jueves,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(id = 5, CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin), NULL)) Viernes,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(id = 6, CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin), NULL)) Sabado,
  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(id = 7, CONCAT(hora_inicio," - ",hora_fin), NULL)) Domingo 
FROM (
  SELECT
    t_dia.id,
    tb_dia_confighorario.hora_inicio,
    tb_dia_confighorario.hora_fin
  FROM tb_dia_confighorario 
    INNER JOIN tb_config_area_comun 
      ON tb_dia_confighorario.idConfigHorario = tb_config_area_comun.id
    INNER JOIN ct_dia 
      ON tb_dia_confighorario.idDia = ct_dia.id 
  WHERE tb_dia_confighorario.idConfigHorario = 1
) X
```

**Resultado:**

| Lunes | Martes | Miercoles | Jueves | Viernes | Sabado | Domingo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 - 11:00 | 10:00 - 11:00,12:00 - 13:00 | 12:00 - 13:00 | 10:00 - 11:00 | 12:00 - 13:00 | 10:00 - 11:00 | 12:00 - 13:00 |

---

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hV9riooeCNfWmxm15okpcm/0)</kbd>